# Where can I find EAR deployment date and time in websphere application server's admin console?

Tags: websphere

Where can I find J2EE application's deployment date and time in websphere application server's admin console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the install date is explicitly recorded anywhere.

However, as an unsupported trick, you can use the timestamps that are embedded in the configuration ids in deployment.xml.

Looking at the deplyment.xml file

`PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cell/applications/APP.ear/deployments/APP/deployment.xml`

the root element will look something like:

```
<appdeployment:Deployment 
 xmi:version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi"
 xmi:id="Deployment_1326844745277">
```

The suffix of `xmi:id` is System.currentTimeMillis():

```
$ perl -e 'print scalar(localtime(1326844745277 / 1000)), "\n"'
Tue Jan 17 17:59:05 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the file system, just check the date for the ear file/folder.